# python stream .tar.gz to s3 while compressing

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AFAIK [AWS allows you to stream your files on the fly directly](https://superuser.com/questions/1248276/aws-upload-folder-to-s3-as-tar-gz-without-compressing-locally), this allows you to compress your files without writing it to disks:

```
tar cvzf - /var/test | aws s3 cp - "s3://tests/test1.tar.gz"
```

I'm trying to perform this action using a ptyhon script, however, I'm quite new working with streams in Python. I've thought that `BytesIO` can help me with this:

Here's my method:

```
def backup_directories(backup_dir):
    #backup_dir is a list with all folders to compress and upload to S3
    d = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    backup_bucket_dir = 'backups'
    for i in backup_dir:
        try:
            client = boto3.client('s3')
            with io.BytesIO() as f:
                with tarfile.open(fileobj=f,mode='w:gz') as tar:
                    tar.add(i,recursive=True)
                key = backup_bucket_dir+'/'+d+'/'+i.split("/")[-1]+'.tar.gz'
                f.seek(0)
                response = client.upload_fileobj(f, 'my-bucket', key)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Failed uploading directory {}, exception {}'.format(i,e))
```

This code works, however, I'm pretty sure that this is not streaming .tar.gz directly to S3 as `bash` does, I think that my code is performing this actions:

1. Create `.tar.gz` in memory.
2. Once `.tar.gz` is created, uploads `.tar.gz` file to S3
3. Release memory

I want that my script works as `bash`, and create tar file on the fly while uploading it to S3.

Could you help me with this? I know I can use `os` module to aproach this, however, I'd rather prefer to use python methods over commands.

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64169859/2537394) focuses on packing multiple files into a tar-archive while streaming it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

If it helps somebody, finally I've decided to use bash commands + AWS cli as:

```
def backup_directories(backup_dir):
    #backup_dir is a list with all folders to compress and upload to S3
    d = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    backup_bucket_dir = 'backups'
    bucket = 's3://my-bucket'
    for i in backup_dir:
        try:
            #Filename to upload
            tar_gz_file = i.split("/")[-1]+'.tar.gz'
            #Key = Complete bucket URL (s3://my-bucket/backups/date/folder_name.tar.gz
            key = bucket + '/' + backup_bucket_dir+'/'+d+'/'+tar_gz_file
            logging.info('Compressing folder {} on the fly, uploading file to AWS folder: {}'.format(i,key))
            try:
                tar = subprocess.Popen(('/usr/bin/tar', 'cvzf', '-', i), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                upload = subprocess.check_output(('/usr/local/bin/aws','s3','cp','-',key), stdin=tar.stdout)
                logging.info('File uploaded sucessfully to {}'.format(key))
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error('Failed compressing folder {}, error: {}'.format(i,e))
            
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Failed uploading directory {}, exception {}'.format(i,e))
```

With this you must have installed and configured aws-cli in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html, a library designed to provide a filesystem-like interface to s3. For example, to create a `.tar.gz`,

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
with s3.open('mybucket/new-file', 'wb') as f:
    with tarfile.open(mode='w|gz', fileobj=f) as tar:
        tar.add("somefile.txt")
```